# How to map view changes to the database MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, viewmodel, repository-pattern

I am new to ViewModel of C# MVC4, and there is a problem that I have been thinking for several days but I could not find the solution.
I want to make a dynamic table which enables users to edit each row, and when users click "save and update" button, the viewModel is return to controller and save the modification to the database.

Here is my viewmodel:

I have used the repository pattern, and I created a layer of service:

```
public class VigiprodView
{
    public IEnumerable<Team> teams { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Vigiprod> vigiprods { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<TeamWeek, Vigiprod> vigiprodbyTeamWeek { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<int, Week> weeks { get; set; }

    public Vigiprod getVigrodByTeamAndWeek(Team team, Week week)
    {   var key = new TeamWeek();
        foreach (var k in vigiprodbyTeamWeek.Keys)
        {
            if ((team.teamId == k.teamId) && (week.weekId == k.weekId ))
            {
                key = k;
                break;
            }
        }
        return vigiprodbyTeamWeek[key];
    }
}

    public class TeamWeek
    {
        public int teamId { get; set; }
        public int weekId { get; set; }
    }
```

In my service, I have written like this:

```
public void saveVigiprodView(VigiprodView vigiprodView)
    {
        foreach (Week week in vigiprodView.weeks.Values)
        {
            this.prodStatusRepository.UpdateWeek(week);
        }
        foreach (Team team in vigiprodView.teams)
        {
            this.prodStatusRepository.updateTeam(team);
        }
        foreach (TeamWeek teamWeek in vigiprodView.vigiprodbyTeamWeek.Keys)
        {
            var teamWeekVigiprod = new TeamWeekVigiprod
            {
                vigiprod = teamWeek.teamId,
                week = teamWeek.weekId,
                team = teamWeek.teamId
            };
            this.prodStatusRepository.updateTeamWeekVigiprod(teamWeekVigiprod);
        }
        this.prodStatusRepository.Save();
    }
```

In my controller, I defined a Edit methode to save viewmodel change to the database:

```
public class ProdStatusController : Controller
{

    [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult EditVigiprod(VigiprodView vigiprod)
   {
        try
        {    
           var service = new ProdstatusService();
           service.saveVigiprodView(vigiprod);
           return RedirectToAction("EditVigiprod");
        }
       catch
        {
            return View("EditVigiprod", vigiprod);
        }
   }
}
```

Well, in my view, I have already successfully display the table correctly, and I have written javascript to realise the editable fonctionality. What I want to know is how to map the action "EditVigiprod" in the view to controller? Here comes my view:

```
 @Model ProdStatus.Models.VigiprodView
```

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "ProdStatus", Model, FormMethod.Post))

```
<input type="submit" name="Save" id="save" value="Save and update" />
<br>
<table id="itable" class="editableTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <div class="out"><b>Weeks</b> <em>Teams</em> </div>
            </th>
            @for (int key = 1; key <= 15; key++)
           {
                <th>
                    @Model.weeks[key].weekNumber
                </th>
           }
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.teams)
     {
            <tr class="stats-row">
                <td>
                    @item.teamName
                </td>

                @for (int key = 1; key <= 15; key++)
       {
                    <td class="vigiprod">
                        @Model.getVigrodByTeamAndWeek(@item, @Model.weeks[key]).label
                    </td>

       }
            </tr>
     }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In my view, I tried to use BeginForm to "bind" the action with controller, but when I click on the button, there is no changement in the database and the page shows me that could not find the view EditVigiprod. I was wondering how to return the viewmodel to the controller from the view.

Thanks very much!!

Comment: BTW... you can always can make that each row is editable in a separate view... or add a save button for each row... that way is easier to send the data to server.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues here...

To send data from your view to the server (your Controller's action) you have 2 options:

1. You need to wrap all your view markup with a FORM element. This can
   be done with the BeginForm or AjaxForm. In this case, the data
   posted to your controller, need to be in INPUTS. In your view, you
   don't use any inputs, so... nothing will be posted.
2. The other option is to do the post using javascript. This will not
   need inputs, you just run a javascript function on button clic, that
   will: get all the values in the view to send to the controller, wrap
   it and do the form post.

It is easier to think about it this way: All the info I want to receive in my Controller Action need to be present in the view and placed in INPUTS. The input can be a TextBox, a DropDownList or a Hidden if you don't want to the data be visible. This needs a mind change when you are coming from ASP.NET WebForms where you have the values of the fields persisted back and forth in the ViewState.  MVC is stateless by default.

So, this will force you to try to post just the needed values and not all the information in the view. Sometimes, all you need to post is an ID of a model... not all the properties since you can get those from database once in the Controller using the ID.

Comment: Nope... once in your client, you don't have the model anymore... you need to get the values from the HTML. So instead of "JSON.stringify(vigiprodViewModel)" you need to recreate using JSON your view model. This is where you will notice that you don't need all that data to be posted again. May be just a collection of id and value changed of something like that. Remember that you Edit (Get) and Edit (Post) can receive different models.